# Windows docker image volume persistance - colon path issue

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to generate a windows image, which creates and persists volume data in the windows user profile folder. Data is collected per user, so it has to be user profile depended. Making all the changes found online, always get errors as in the image. What might be the issue? Local machine env holds the value; I have cross-checked the env variable value via Powershell.

```
volumes:
      - ./devops/https/ngtcert.pfx:/https/aspnetapp.pfx:ro
      - "${USERPROFILE}/source/:${USERPROFILE}/source/"
```

[image]

Image expect to create a source folder either to be created or persist the existing data.

However, i couldn't resolve this issue.

Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key issue was

1. `user:  "ContainerAdministrator"` was missing. When running a windows docker. user should be mentioned.
2. The folder path should be in windows format

````
services:
  directoryservice:
    user:  "ContainerAdministrator"
    # build:
    #   context: .
    #   dockerfile: api-win.Dockerfile
    # image: apiwin:latest
    image: abcd.azurecr.io/api-windows:113133
    ports:
      - "44309:44309"
    environment:
      - COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=123#
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=C:\https\apicert.pfx
    volumes:
      - ./devops/https:C:\https:ro
      - ${USERPROFILE}\source:C:\source:rw```
````