# Docker persist windows userprofile folder data

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile

Is below Dockerfile valid. The intention is to persist the user profile folder volume.

eg: C:\Users\INaBJOJ1\source in windows

```
# escape=`
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
COPY . App/
WORKDIR /App
EXPOSE 44309
VOLUME ${USERPROFILE}\source\
RUN echo ${USERPROFILE}\source\
# RUN dir c:\
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="Development"
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://+:44309;"
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Service.dll"]
```

Comment: suggest use asp.net default dockerfile syntax. are you modify it in a way, that you build code on your host(windows), and the source code along with binaries copied to docker, then docker use the binaries to run?

Comment: @VolkanOrhan Usually VOLUME in Dockerfile only has a destination path in the container. I may be wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have explaied the resolved version here - [Windows docker image volume persistance - colon path issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71328864/windows-docker-image-volume-persistance-colon-path-issue/71567016#71567016)

```
services:
  directoryservice:
    user:  "ContainerAdministrator"
    # build:
    #   context: .
    #   dockerfile: api-win.Dockerfile
    # image: apiwin:latest
    image: abcd.azurecr.io/api-windows:113133
    ports:
      - "44309:44309"
    environment:
      - COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=123#
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=C:\https\apicert.pfx
    volumes:
      - ./devops/https:C:\https:ro
      - ${USERPROFILE}\source:C:\source:rw
```